# How to open a new Terminal Window instead of a new Tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal, release-hera, app-shortcuts

I am using elementary OS 5.1 Hera.
The shortcut `Super+T` in previous versions (in elementary 5 and older) opened a **new Terminal Window** . Now it opens **a new Tab** in an existing Terminal Window (which in my case is most of the time on another workspace!) How can I change it back to open a new Terminal Window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found for the same problem is to make a new Custom shortcut - **System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom shortcut** , click on the little **+** on the bottom left side of the right pannel, then add a custom command `io.elementary.terminal -n` and in the right of it click/tap the **Disabled** and then use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. The system will inform you that you are about to change the default shortcut for the terminal command, you have to accept it and once you do this using the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will open a new window instead of a new tab. If there is no terminal app opened and you have history into privacy & security enabled, the first time it will open all the tabs from your last session, and the next time will be a new window on the current space you are (before doing this it opens a new tab even if you are in another space then the terminal app is opened).

If this works for you, please accept the answer (click/tap on the grey thickbox on the left side), if it doesn't - post a comment what is happening or not. It is necessary to have the latest terminal version installed, use `sudo apt update` to check if you have updates for the terminal before you post a comment if this solution do not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new change in behaviour introduced in a recent version of terminal, the -n flag is now needed to open a new window so the shortcut no longer opens a new window. You can revert to the previous behaviour by re-assigning super-t in settings to 'io.elementary.terminal -n'.